# How to fill excepted fields with blanks without repeated code?

Tags: python, selenium, exception

I am running a web scraping program that grabs certain data fields from a site, however I have no guarantee that all fields will be present on a given page. If a field does not exist it should be blank. As it currently stands my code looks like this

```
try:
    field1 = scrape_data_field1(field1)
except NotOnPageError:
    field1 = ""

try:
    field2 = scrape_data_field2(field2)
except NotOnPageError:
    field2 = ""

try:
    field3= scrape_data_field3(field3)
except NotOnPageError:
    field3 = ""
```

I cant group these fields together in the same try-except block because then they would all be filled in as blank if even one was missing. Is there a more elegant solution to this problem than the clunky one I am currently doing? If it is relevant I am using selenium to scrape data from the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered binding your `field` variables to their related functions within in an iterable structure? This would allow you to iterate over the structure and apply the same logic to function/variable set.

The below approach seems to solve your issue quite neatly, accounting for the fact that it would be inappropriate to put all of this logic in a single `try`/`except` structure as the first exception raised would necessarily halt any further fields from being tried - as highlighted in your original post.

```py
field_mapping = [
{"field": field1, "function": scrape_data_field1},
{"field": field2, "function": scrape_data_field2},
{"field": field3, "function": scrape_data_field3}
]

for m in field_mapping:
    try:
        m["function"](m["field"])
    except NotOnPageError:
        m["field"] = ""
```

As you can see, this solution essentially groups each `field` with its corresponding `scrape_data_field` function as values within a `dict`. These `dict` structures are stored in a `list` that can be iterated over so that the same logic can be applied to each variable/function pairing - i.e. each function is executed with the paired `field` data passed at runtime.

Comment: ah, I am now realizing that I have asked my question slightly wrong. I cannot use the same scrape_data() function for each field. The query is actually slightly different which I should have made clear (i.e field1 = scrape_field1(), etc) Should I amend the question or accept this answer considering you have answered the questions I asked?

Comment: I would amend the question and I will loop back 'round to update/delete my answer as necessary in light of changes. Unfortunately I'm just leaving the house now and doubt that I will get a chance to answer any updates to the question until tomorrow.

Comment: @JoshZwiebel Just to let you know, I've updated my answer based on the changes you have outlined here and in your edits to OP.

Answer (score 0):

One strategy might be to make a function that takes in the function `scrape_data_field1`, and the argument'field1' and returns the result of the try except.

```
def try_execpt_scrape_data(field, _function):
    try:
        field_out = _function(field)
    except:
        field_out = ""

    return field_out

def _function(argument):
    return_this = argument * argument
    return return_this

field1 = 3

field_out = try_execpt_scrape_data(field1, _function)
print(field_out)
```